# AppStore is testing my App on Ipad devices

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

We're submitting to review our app. AppStore is rejecting the build because the application is crashing on Ipad device running iOS 14. But, on our Xcode settings, we just have checked the iPhone field on Build Settings ( see image ). Is there a workaround to restrict our application just for iPhone devices?[image]

Comment: If you have hardware requirements for something that's only on an iPhone, you can/should make that part of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your plist.  Otherwise, it's expected that a non-universal app will run on an iPad while looking like a phone display.

Comment: Oh. I get it. Our Info.plist file has the value armv7 on that key:

 `<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>armv7</string>`
You mean to put all the keys like gps, bluethooth-le, camera-flash?. But, Which keys should I use to ensure that the AppStore will not test the artifact on iPad? Thanks!

Comment: The correct answer is to fix the crash on the iPad. Even if your app isn't universal it should run on an iPad.  Even if you used some device capability that prevented an iPad install today, Apple could release a new iPad tomorrow with the required hardware.

Comment: The other consideration is that if you put in a requirement that you don't actually need, you may get a rejection for that.  Also, if you have a crash condition, how do you know it won't show up on the *next* iPhone?